# Methods used in pyspark for RDD object

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a beginner in Pyspark. I'm using it as I have to run my algorithm on large data and derive the outcome in real time. So I have made an RDD object from a python numpy array say ,*X* by

> 

```
from pyspark import SparkContext , SparkConf
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

X = sc.parallelize(X)
```

Now I'm getting error if I use the methods of numpy say shape then it shows an error massage by showing
**"'RDD' object has no attribute 'shape'"**. And there are other methods in numpy arrays which I cann't apply here . So I think there should have alternative methods in RDD similar to numpy  array methods.Can you give me some resources where can I learn those methods. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays and RDDs are different. Numpy arrays reside on runtime memory, whereas RDDs, Resilient Distributed Datasets, reside on Spark HDFS, used to do perform data-heavy operations in parallel and effectively in a distributed environment.

`someRDD = sc.parallelize(numpyArray`)

converted numpyArray into RDD, and you will not be able to use numpy methods on someRDD any more.

However, you can achieve similar functionalities using operations defined in the spark documentation :
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html